# Ruby on Rails omniauth-facebook works in development, but fails in production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, heroku, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook in my app. Everything works great on development. Once I upload to heroku (I made another facebook app so compensate for the url change in production). I am able to get to the facebook sign in page using mysitename.heroku.com/auth/facebook. However, after I log in and click the accept/allow button, there is a failure and the OmniAuth.config.on_failure function is processed and I go to my error screen.

Here is the error I get when I do [200, {}, [env['omniauth.error'].inspect]] in my .on_failure function:

```
#<OAuth2::Error: : 
{"error":{"message":"Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.","type":"OAuthException","code":191}}>
```

Here is the logs that seem to be relevant from the command: heroku logs

```
2013-08-27T22:44:20.842352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook" for 174.21.250.137 at 2013-08-27 22:44:20 +0000
2013-08-27T22:44:20.857734+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/auth/facebook host=warm-anchorage-4172.herokuapp.com fwd="174.21.250.137" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=26ms status=302 bytes=262
2013-08-27T22:44:21.229031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-08-27T22:44:21.228882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-08-27T22:44:21.609111+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQD4g5_eZRBzwOOvl_qI64mnKtk1b4048YuGXVyBjfxer9QrSBgiMwL8Nxsr0yducrL1DMfK3EdNS5E8qljb7BWvSoIoysfXF3tbIs6_7VkV2LiRVfrmZ8goku1MweG46hagJtatAJTbVfZkE6VL4t-pX169DCrn6TRhkfJoNAnRF8Xs2wHbPg1pwsUOOi_BJdRXNx9noZ8Cnc51unUVVKez-MStbD9OfDST5PNZNJzZJhaXiC_K2JpTg2S2z8tptsEAFf-gV5Rim86tN66FTCLG-HVhKBHp3bJgiYdC0160Kp8m0oKrO9lwMJQr6NBTOSw&state=fd82e1208e9848d0deda8271118799c38c4350f9c9f95fc6" for 174.21.250.137 at 2013-08-27 22:44:21 +0000
2013-08-27T22:44:21.609111+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQD4g5_eZRBzwOOvl_qI64mnKtk1b404YuGXVyBjfxer9QrSBgiMwL8Nxsr0yducrL1DMfK3EdNS5E8qljb7BWvSoIoysfXF3tbIs6_7VkV2LiRVfrmZ8goku1MweG46hagJtatAJTbVfZkE6VL4t-pX169DCrn6TRhkfJoNAnRF8Xs2wHbPg1pwsUOOi_BJdRXNx9noZ8Cnc51unUVVKez-MStbD9OfDST5PNZNJzZJhaXiC_K2JpTg2S2z8tptsEAFf-gV5Rim86tN66FTCLG-HVhKBHp3bJgiYdC0160Kp8m0oKrO9lwMJQr6NBTOSwstate=fd82e1208e9848d0deda8271118799c38c4350f9c995fc6" for 174.21.250.137 at 2013-08-27 22:44:21 +0000
2013-08-27T22:44:21.700789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQD4g5_eZRBzwOOvl_qI64mnKtk1b4048YuGXVyBjfxer9QrSBgiMwL8Nxsr0yducrL1DMfK3EdNS5E8qljb7BWvSoIoysfXF3tbIs6_7VkV2LiRVfrmZ8goku1MweG46hagJtatAJTbVfZkE6VL4t-pX169DCrn6TRhkfJoNAnRF8Xs2wHbPg1pwsUOOi_BJdRXNx9noZ8Cnc51unUVVKez-MStbD9OfDST5PNZNJzZJhaXiC_K2JpTg2S2z8tptsEAFf-gV5Rim86tN66FTCLG-HVhKBHp3bJgiYdC0160Kp8m0oKrO9lwMJQr6NBTOSw&state=fd82e1208e9848d0deda8271118799c38c4350f9c9f95fc6 host=warm-anchorage-4172.herokuapp.com fwd="174.21.250.137" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=114ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-08-27T22:44:22.939414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-08-27T22:44:34.222678+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-27 22:44:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-08-27T22:44:34.222781+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-27 22:44:34] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=13228
2013-08-27T22:44:34.222678+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-27 22:44:34] INFO  ruby 1.9.3   (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
```

Here is what my omniauth.rb looks like:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  if Rails.env.production?
    provider :facebook, "********72531693", "*******32c00b6bd32b70fa939e6a7c1"
    {:scope => 'PERMISSION_1, PERMISSION_2, PERMISSION_3...', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
  end
    provider :facebook, "********45876931", "*******2abe337c16c135f06404c91a"
    {:scope => 'PERMISSION_1, PERMISSION_2, PERMISSION_3...', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
end

OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
  UsersController.action(:omniauth_failure).call(env)
  #this will invoke the omniauth_failure action in UsersController.
end
```

So I'm not for sure, but I feel pretty confident its a heroku issue since it works perfect in development on my localhost:3000. Both my apps are nearly identical on facebook for my dev and production version other than the host url. Since I am able to at least attempt to log in, I don't think it has anything to do with the facebook setup. I tried using both omniauth-facebook 1.4.0 and 1.4.1.

Adding my routes files, just in case somebody sees something that I don't see.

```
root  'welcome#index'
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',  via: 'get'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
match '/signout',  to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#createfb', via: 'get'
```

Comment: What are your Facebook settings? Have you checked all the URLs (Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, etc)?

Comment: All my facebook url settings are blank except for the "Website with Facebook Login" which is set to http://<my site name>.herokuapp.com. All others are empty. I double and triple checked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you've set up your Facebook application to use "localhost" or some development server URL as it's callback. It's failing in production because the URL of your production server is not configured as part of the app. Check the app settings.

Edit: I can see a section called "Website with Facebook Login" that has a field called "Site URL". Are you sure you haven't set it to `localhost:3000`?

Comment: So, like I mentioned above, I have to apps, one for production and one for development. I double checked and made sure my development "website for facebook login" was pointing to localhost:300 while my production was pointing to http://myappname.herokuapp.com. All other URLs are left blank. Also, I can get to the login screen for facebook. However, after I log in, I then get the error, only on production. So, the only URL I set is correct and I can to the /facebook/auth page successfully. Just after login, there is an error.

Comment: @JosephBui Do you have some updates about this issue?